# How do you search for particular features?

Tags: featuretools

At last when I tried featuretools I was searching for a particular feature which I was expecting. When you have > 30 feature it is kind of time consuming to find the feature.

Has the feature_names object (second return object of the dfs method) a method to search for some text patterns (regex)?

feature_names is a list of "featuretools.feature_base.feature_base.IdentityFeature"

Post Scriptum: In the featuretools documentation of the API the return objects are not described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep Feature Synthesis returns feature objects. If you call `FeatureBase.get_name()` on one of those objects, it will return the name as a string. You can use this to implement whatever selection logic you'd like. For example, here is the code to make a list of all feature objects where `amount` is in the name

```py
import featuretools as ft

es = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)

fl = ft.dfs(target_entity="customers", entityset=es, features_only=True)

keep = []

for feature in fl:
    if "amount" in feature.get_name():
        keep.append(feature)
```